# How can I use a sublist in place of the full list in a computation

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I use a sublist in place the full list in a computation, but refer to it by the name of the full list.

I have a list

```
allData={{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}};
```

For a particular evaluation I would like to get rid of the last 2 parts to get

```
allData = {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}};
```

But for a different evaluation I want to keep everything.

So is there a way how to quickly uncomment `Delete` or replace the `part specification` with... nothing?

```
Delete[allData(*,{{3},{4}}*)]
```

returns, obviously,

> `Delete[{{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}]`

Of course, in reality `Delete` is just one of many functions applied to `allData`.

Comment: Use an empty list.

Comment: Are you aware of the keyboard shortcut for commenting / uncommenting? You can select code and, on Windows, press Alt + `/` to toggle the comment status of your selection.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Should I delete this question? Because your answer, obviously, works. Thank you.

Comment: Probably I did not understand you right, but what I get from your question is a feeling that you are afraid to spoil the list allData, right? If yes, nothing forces you to change the allData list. Why do not you create a new list like `allDataNew=Take[allData,2]`?

Comment: @MarcoB or left click + u. Yes, I am aware of that. The embarrassing problem was that I had no clue how 'empty list' would work.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch That would be an approach, yes. Something I actually used before, but sometimes it really slows down, e.g., you have to start thinking which data set to use. A quick (un)comment-test is easier in my case. Anyway, I feel that the answer ('empty list') is so basic (in a good way!) that maybe this question should be closed (deleted) because "this question arises due to a simple mistake" or "easily found in the documentation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not  fool around with `Delete` or commenting or uncommenting. Instead I would enclose the particular computation that needs only the 1st two elements in `Block`.

Example

```
data = {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2} ,{a3, b3, c3}};
Block[{data = data[[;; 2]]}, data^2]
```

> `{{a^2, b^2, c^2}, {a1^2, b1^2, c1^2}}`

But `data` is unchanged.

data

> `{{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2} ,{a3, b3, c3}};`